# Reformat data, Pivot Table lookup?

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, filter, pivot-table

I am attempting to set up a formula to duplicate & reformat some dates and times from UK date (dd/mm/yyyy) & 24hr time, to US date (mm/dd/yyyy) and H:MM AM/PM time format - without changing the original entries or reformatting (they need to stay that way for UK users).
Also, to take the data from vertical columns to horizontal for each date.

There may be several dates, each with 1-4 'Start Time's associated with it.

So this data:

[image: Data set 1]

Is duplicated within the sheet and becomes this format:
[image: Reformatted data]

Here is a google document to show what I mean, that you are welcome to edit;
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13dLkXo803Oz4jtlvUmMDWtV8mMF60fjb-BimzQu9Lxk/edit?usp=sharing

Now I've used a Pivot table to concatenate the data by date, and return the times horizontally in a row, and to reformat the date & time formats, however I'm struggling to write a formula that can look up the data in the pivot table and return it to the original sheet as intended.

**My first attempt** (in the sheet below, cell G5):

=FILTER('Pivot Table 1'!$C$3:$H$3, 'Pivot Table 1'!$C$2:$H$2=F5)

which returns an error 'No matches are found in FILTER evaluation'

**My second attempt** (in the sheet, cell G6):

=GETPIVOTDATA("Start Time", 'Pivot Table 1'!A1, "Date Field", FILTER('Pivot Table 1'!$B$3:$B='Post New Events V2'!F5, 'Pivot Table 1'!$A$3:$H), "Date", "Start Time")

which returns an error 'FILTER range must be a single row or a single column'

I'm open to suggestions, perhaps I am going about this the wrong way. Perhaps some sort of array formula is the way to proceed? Perhaps I am too lost in the weeds to see the solution to this clearly. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: One question, you want to do everything with the formula and stop using the Pivot table or just extract the data in the pivot table?

Comment: @S H Getting the dates and their correspondent times from the range you have can be done easily with formulas, why the need of a pivot table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this something like this do it?

```
=
SORT(
LET(d,UNIQUE(A14:INDEX(A14:A,COUNTA(A14:A))),
{INDEX(TEXT(d,"mm/dd/yyyy")),LET(f,SPLIT(MAP(d,LAMBDA(e,TEXTJOIN("|",1,FILTER(B14:B,A14:A=e)))),"|"),INDEX(IF(f="","",TEXT(f,"h:MM AM/PM"))))}))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, yeah this is excellent & sorts the data into the right format. Fantastic stuff Martín - a very interesting formula I'll spend some time digesting & getting to understand!

Comment: I'm glad it was useful! Updated it to not appear undesired 12:00 AM when there's an empty value